# I have a problem with my lighting and shadow

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, light, shadows

I use cycles GPU. My light source is at left but the shadow also at the left. I think that the point light did'nt work and it uses scene light. I try to tick on the scene world under viewport shading and it turn all dark. I even don't understand the lighting option under the viewport shading. And when I render, the picture is darker than preview. Thanks for your help!

[image]

[image: After rendered]

Answer (score 2):

The second screenshot shows a correct preview, since *Scene Lights* and *Scene World* are enabled. If *Scene World* is disabled, an HDRI is used to light the scene preview. With *Scene Lights* off, your point light is ignored, hence the wrong shadow. The options are explained in the [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/controls/shading.html#material-preview).

> **Scene Lights**
>
> Use the lights in the scene when rendering the scene.
>
> **Scene World**
>
> Use the world of the scene when rendering the scene. When turned off a world will be constructed with the next options.
>
> - **HDRI Environment**
>
>   The environment map used to light the scene.
> - **Rotation**
>
>   The rotation of the environment on the Z axis.
> - **Strength**
>
>   Light intensity of the environment.
> - **Background**
>
>   The opacity level of a very blurred version of > the HDRI will be rendered as background in the 3D View.

Comment: If you want to modify the actual world settings used for the final render, then you will have to go to the *World Properties* or use the node editor.

Comment: If I turn on or turn off the scene light, the shadow still at its place (left side) even tough the point light at the left side. I think no change when I turn on or off the scene light. The change is at the scene world only, it becomes dark when turned on.

Comment: Both need to be enabled in order to give you an accurate preview for your final render. It's dark because you only have a point light in your scene and your world has the default grey color. You can add an HDRI to the world which will be used in the final render, however that has to be configured in the world tab or in the node editor, *not* in the viewport settings. You could also add other lights, like a sun, point, spot or area light and setup a [three point lighting](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RDbrOpnIY7Q).

Comment: The incorrect shadow with *Scene World* off is caused by the HDRI that is loaded (as shown in your first screenshot). The light direction for it apparently comes from an opposite direction, but since it's much stronger than your point light, it still casts a shadow (despite your point light being there). If you adjust the rotation slider, the shadow should move.

Comment: okay thank you. Really appreciate that!

Comment: @AzizAkmal. Please don't add thank you as a comment, upvote the answer instead. If you feel it completely solved your problem consider marking it accepted